# Button for website not working for iphone/ipads

Tags: html, css, ios

hi i have a client's website which is working well on Computer browsers but is having issues when viewing in Apple products. The website URL is http://holmesdesign.stage.centuryware.org, if you scroll down to the bottom of the page, there is a form with checkboxes. User should click on at least one checkboxes to fill up the form, howver it is just not clickable using apple products. Can someone advise what actually went wrong? Thanks!

Below is the script:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Buy" onclick="javascript:checkBoxValidate(0)" id="checkbox0" name="checkbox" class="chkclass">


.chkclass {
  background-image: url("images/check-on.png") !important;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 43px;
  width: 43px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
```

If the checkbox isn't visible, then you can't click it. It would seem some browsers capture the click of the label and perform a click on the checkbox, while others don't.

For styling, you could overlay the checkbox on top of the label:

```
<div style="
    position: relative;
">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox1" onclick="checkBoxValidate(1)" value="Rent" class="" style="
    position: absolute;
">
    <label for="checkbox1" id="labelchk1" class="" style="
    position: absolute;
">Click-Me</label></div>
```

And add this to the checkbox style:

```
width: 43px;
height: 43px;
display: block;
opacity: 0;
```

Personally, I would make my own checkbox out of a DIV if I wanted to change its appearance. All you need is a click to toggle the value to 0 and 1, and change the CSS class to checked or unchecked. This would be trivial in jQuery. In order to send the data across for the form, you could use either a hidden checkbox or a `hidden` input and set its value as well.

Comment: Hi Aram, Thanks for the quick response. Let me try it out and get back to the answer. :)